# Can't convert Date to Number

Tags: excel, vba

I have a userform and I take start and end dates from user as in dd.mm.yyyy format. To make it easier to compare dates, I want to turn it to a double or long type of value. I have tried as in below but it gives me an error of type mismatch.

[image]

endDate is already defined as Double and as you can see, Me.g_end.Value is string in proper format. Why do I get this error, and how can I handle it?

Also I need to add, DateValue(Me.g_end.Value) works fine with my friend to get value of date who uses Excel 2013. I use Excel 2016.

Comment: Try converting with `CDate` [link](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cdate.php)

Comment: Already tried. @PeterT

Comment: If CDate doesn't convert then maybe cdate(join(split(me.g_end.value2, chr(46)), chr(47))). Be careful on DMY vs MDY dates; your example is ambiguous. btw, use a Long and save using doubles for datetimes when they are necessary.

Comment: It seems like I have a missing reference. I ll go into that. What to do with this question?

Comment: @alisrn It's not a missing reference. That is not a valid date format.

Comment: how it is not valid? @ashleedawg

Comment: @alisrn - see my answer below for one way to find your correct date format.

Comment: @Jeeped Value2 is not valid. Changed it to value. but still got the mismatch error. also changed to my endDate to date.

Comment: Right. It's a form text box. My bad, but the edit period on that comment has expired.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enter dates in a valid format in order for Excel to recognize them as dates.

As far as I know, **nowhere** uses dots (periods) in dates.  (As I recall, nowadays only one country in the world even recognizes dots as am official date separator.)

Click your <kbd>Start</kbd> menu and type `Region` to find and open Windows **Region and Language Settings**.

Note the format that your system is expecting for **Short Date**, ***including the symbol*** between each date part, and try entering your dates in Excel like that.

[image: img]